# How much a UIScrollView has been scrolled inside a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how much of the scroll view inside my `UIPageViewController` has been scrolled. I have the following code in the viewLoad that access the `UIScrollView` from `UIPageViewController`.

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) 
    {
        thisControl = (UIScrollView *)view;
    }
}
```

So once I have the UIScrollView, called thisControl I would like to print how much has been scrolled by doing something like this:

```
NSLog (@"Scroll: %f",thisControl.contentOffset.x);
```

The problem, is that I don't really know where to put this line, or how print continuously how much has been scrolled. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the delegate to that controller(`myScroll.delegate = self;`) and then add this method:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
  CGFloat y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
  NSLog(@"%f",y);
  // some stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, I think looks good but doesn't work. It gaves me a warning of 
Assigning to 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>' from imcompatible type, and then it just prints 0.000000000

Comment: Ups, sorry my mistake, I'm moving the screen horizontally so it must be CGFloat x = scrollView.contentOffset.x; instead of y, now works perfect. Many thanks!

Comment: in the .h file you have to add the UIScrollViewDelegate