# How to allow scrollview subviews to respond to scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, dynamic, uiscrollview, subview

I am developing a media based application for iOS, It has a scrollview which has three subviews in it - a UIImageView, a title UILabel and a UIButton.
When I scroll the scrollview I want the UILabel to be fixed (i.e it shouldn't scroll with the scrollview) untill the UIImageView scrolls up completely.

Please can you help me, how can I keep the title label frame at a constant height until the scroll view scrolls to a certain height.

Comment: @Mohit, no I have not tried it yet, I am not sure how to achieve this. Part of this image is hidden below uilabels. So I want to start uilabels to scroll only after the UIImageView is scrolled to visible. (Sorry can't post the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first make sure the UILabel isn't a subview of the scroll view. Then add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your view controller class. Then in your .m file add

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
  CGFloat y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
  if (y > (your number here)) {
    // Do something with the UILabel
  }
}
```

[Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768550/how-much-a-uiscrollview-has-been-scrolled-inside-a-uipageviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks Kent but the real issue is, we need the Label present on the top of scroll view but it should not scroll until the UIImageView is completely visible, so how to add the UILabel on the top of scroll view so that it is visible, but should not scroll